# How do I edit a block pattern of mine?

Tags: block-editor

I'm posting here because, seems impossible, but can't find anything in google, nor in docs. I just created a couple of patterns from Gutenberg. Now I see there's something to adjust. How can I edit them? And what id I want to completely delete them?

I mean, not after adding them to the content editor. I mean the 'prototypes'. The objects I just created. It seems they're available as patterns to use, but cannot change them. Seems really strange to me.

Some writes I have to use the site editor, but my current theme is not one of the modern  full site editor themes.

Comment: what process did you use to create the patterns? There are multiple methods and the answer depends on which you used

Comment: I built them from Gutenberg. I'm a developer but I'm just helping a friend of mine to layout her website. It's a pre-installed wordpress, so I don't have much access to code. I'm trying to do all from the admin.

Comment: with 'from gutenberg' I mean: designed in gutenberg then saved as patterns.

Comment: can you be very specific about what you mean by "saved as patterns", there are multiple types of patterns, and multiple ways to register them that are very different. E.g. you might be talking about a synced pattern, or you might be trying to say you used the `register_pattern` function in PHP, or that you used javascript to register patterns, or that you used the pattern creator on the .org library, etc etc, we need to know how you saved the pattern to understand your question

Comment: note that if you're talking about a "synced pattern" then you should make sure you always refer to it as a synced pattern as they are not the same as "patterns", they're created stored and behave differently and it has major consequences for your question as the name is the only thing they share ( synced patterns === reusable blocks, they are stored in the database. Block patterns are not )

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you but i think you didn't understand very well what I wrote. Again, I did all in admin, gutenberg, so no php and no js. From the tree block  navigator, you can 'save as pattern' a block or section. When saving, you can name the pattern, choose or create a category and flag if it's synced or not. In my case, i do not use synced patterns.

Comment: hmmm note that this stack is for developers so this might have been better asked on the .org support forums. Can you edit that description (bonus points for screenshots) into your question? Unless someone reads through my comments and questions and your responses they won't be able to understand, it would save a lot of time and effort that could have been used to write an answer

Comment: In my question I wrote: "I just created a couple of patterns from Gutenberg", and then, second comment: "I'm a developer".

Comment: my suspicion is that this is listed in the site editor, but if you don't have block template support in your theme the site editor doesn't show removing the ability to edit/manage them once they're created. Re: developer the expectation is that you can program and expect an answer that requires code, since this is a programming stack, but if you're asking where something in the UI is then that's not a developer question but a user support question, especially since UI's in gutenberg change are heavily in flux

Comment: Yes, ok. To be true, I hoped, I considered that maybe there could be also some coding ways (or at least from db) to do some edit or even simply delete the wrong ones. But you're right,  the question is quite border line.

Answer (score 0):

This is done via the site editor, which is the editor option under the appearance menu, in the site editors patterns menu:

[image]

Note that if the site editor is not available on your site then this UI will be out of reach.

There is an admin screen that's linked to though, you *might* be able to use that `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=wp_block`